# Relative Answer and Comment Times Are Wrong

Tags: bug

The relative comment times appear to be wrong. I [answered a question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/103866/the-uploaded-file-exceeds-the-upload-max-filesize-directive-in-php-ini/103869#103869) two days ago as you can see in the screenshot yet the relative time still says it was answered 'yesterday'.

[image: Wrong relative times.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stack Exchange seems to use a definition of "yesterday", of  "between 24 and 48 hours elapsed". See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11/how-do-i-calculate-relative-time/12#12

So rather than "in previous calendar day", it means "it hasn't been two days since".